# ошибка в прогамме на питон

Tags: python, python-3.x

в чем ошибка? и как исправить?

```
d = {1: 'Очень плохо', 2: 'Плохо', 3: 'Удовлетворительно', 4: 'Хорошо', 5: 'Отлично'}
try:
print(d[int(input('Введите балл > '))])
except ValueError:
print('Введен неверный балл.')
except KeyError:
print('Введен неверный балл.')
```

Comment: в чём ошибка-то?

Comment: В чем ошибка написано в сообщении об ошибке. Надо бы не только писать, но хотя бы иногда и читать.

Comment: @Эникейщик, скажи, пожалуйста, а ты специально без табов исправление сделал?

Comment: @JackWolf как было так и сделал. Может, в этом и ошибка как раз, от нас же скрывают.

Comment: @Эникейщик, справедливо

Answer (score 2):

Вот так исправить.

```py
d = {1: 'Очень плохо', 2: 'Плохо', 3: 'Удовлетворительно', 4: 'Хорошо', 5: 'Отлично'}
try:
    print(d[int(input('Введите балл > '))])
except ValueError:
    print('Введен неверный балл.')
except KeyError:
    print('Введен неверный балл.')
```

В `Python` ключевую роль играют отступы. Если отступов нет - программа либо будет работать неправильно, либо не будет работать вообще.

Результаты:

```
Введите балл > 4
Хорошо
```

```
Введите балл > 6
Введен неверный балл.
```

```
Введите балл > wasd
Введен неверный балл.
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае проблема с синтаксисом, если вы не уверены в своих силах, ознакомьтесь с книгой ["Укус питона"](https://myrobot.ru/downloads/books/A_Byte_of_Python_Rus_2.01.pdf)

```
d = {1: 'Очень плохо', 2: 'Плохо', 3: 'Удовлетворительно', 4: 'Хорошо', 5: 'Отлично'} 
try:
   print(d[int(input('Введите балл > '))]) #5 -> Отлично
except ValueError:
   print('Введен неверный балл.')
except KeyError:
   print('Введен неверный балл.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще `try-except-else`:

```
d = {1: 'Очень плохо', 2: 'Плохо', 3: 'Удовлетворительно', 4: 'Хорошо', 5: 'Отлично'}
try:
    print(d[int(input('Введите балл > '))])

except ValueError:
    print('Введен неверный балл.')

else:
    print('Введен неверный балл.')
```